# I want to change date formate for Kendo ui Schedule at Header

Tags: kendo-ui, date-format, kendo-scheduler

```
$("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
  date: new Date(),
  currentTimeMarker: false,
  views: [
    "day", "week", "workWeek"
  ]
});
```

like above code the default date formate in header will be MM/dd/yyyy but
i need to modifiy that format.[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We can modify code as following.

```
$("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
    date: new Date("2013/6/13"),
    startTime: new Date("2013/6/13 7:00"),
    height: 400,
    timezone: "Etc/UTC",
    views: [`enter code here`
        "day",
        { 
          type: "week", 
          selected: true, 
          dateHeaderTemplate: "<span class='k-link k-nav-day'>#=kendo.toString(date, 'ddd dd/M')#</span>"
        },
        "month",
        "agenda"
    ],
```

and in the asp.net MVC we can use

```
.Views(views =>
  {
      views.DayView(d => d.DateHeaderTemplate("<span class='k-link k-nav-day'>#=kendo.toString(date, 'ddd dd/M')#</span>"));
      views.WeekView(w => w.DateHeaderTemplate("<span class='k-link k-nav-day'>#=kendo.toString(date, 'ddd dd/M')#</span>"));
      views.MonthView();`enter code here`
      views.AgendaView();
  })
```